# How to copy and paste files or directories in Windows using C without system()

Tags: c

I am making a basic file explorer, so i would like to include copy and paste function in my program. I am not working in any GUI environment and win32api.

I have LCRS tree,

In which C: drive is parent
and its first folder is left child, and remaining are right sibling

So when I select any child or sibling node for copy and choose its destination, all contents should be pasted in a desired location.

It can be done with system() with cp command and mkdir() function. Is there another way ?

also tell me how can I open files in their associated applications ? like abc.txt opens in notepad.

Comment: `fread()`, `fwrite()`.

Comment: It can work with files. How about directories ? should I match directory name and put it in mkdir()? @H2CO3

Comment: @userXXXX pretty much yes.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Please, answer my second question. How can I open files in their associated applications @H2CO3.

Comment: @userXXX Sorry, I don't know that, I don't use/program Windows.

Comment: To open a file with its associated application, use ShellExecute() function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but Sir, I mentioned earlier that I am not using win32api so I don't have access to "ShellExecute()" function.

Comment: Why don't you use WinAPI? If you are writing a file manager you must deal with file attributes, permissions etc. If you want to interact with system, and if you write a file manager you probably want, you should use WinAPI...

Comment: For this purpose, I am using dirent.h and sys/stat.h. The reason of not using WinAPI is I am a beginner and this is my first application :-). @el.pescado .

Comment: Opening files in their associated applications requires the Windows API (ShellExecute/ShellExecuteEx), and those API calls use other API calls to find the association information in the Windows Registry. You're not going to be able to do it without using the Windows API, even if you wanted to write your own. (Software installations set up the associations when they're installed, and they don't know anything about your program; they use the Windows API too.) You're also going to run into issues with user privileges, UAC, networking, etc.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I decided to learn WinAPI for my Application :-).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wrapper using [SHFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647743.aspx). It can be used to copy *most* files or directories; there are a few exceptions (e.g. attempting to copy directories that you don't have permission to access, or special folders such as My Documents to remote networks). It'll return `0` upon success.

```
#include <Shellapi.h>
int Copy(PCZZTSTR source, PCZZTSTR destination) {
    return SHFileOperation(&(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW){ .wFunc  = FO_COPY,
                                               .pFrom  = source,
                                               .pTo    = destination,
                                               .fFlags = FOF_SILENT
                                                       | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR
                                                       | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION
                                                       | FOF_NOERRORUI
                                                       | FOF_NO_UI });
}
```